# Objective C: Difference between self and super

Tags: objective-c, self, super

I am new to Objective C.I am trying aout some example programs.I could not understand how the self and super methods work in objective C. In the pgm below CashTransaction.m [super trackSpending:amount] is called and in CreditCardTransaction.m [self trackSpending:amount] is called.I could not find difference between the self and super.super is for invoking the base class overriden method.and self is for invoking the child class overridden method.This is what my understanding is.please correct me if i'm wrong.Thanks in advace.

### main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BudgetObject.h"
#import "Transaction.h"
#import "CashTransaction.h"
#import "CreditCardTransaction.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        //!---Creating An Object And Allocating It With Values---
        Budget* budget = [Budget new];
        [budget createBudget:1000.00 withExchangeRate:1.2500];

        //!---Declaring And Adding Elements To An Array---
        NSMutableArray* transactions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
        Transaction* aTransaction; 
        aTransaction = [Transaction new];
        [transactions addObject:aTransaction];

        //!---Calculating The No Of Elements In An Array---
        int k;
        k=[transactions count];
        NSLog(@"The count value is:%d",k);

        //!---Selecting According To The Type Of Transaction---
    for(Transaction *iTransaction in transactions){
         switch ([aTransaction returnType]) {
                case cash:
                        [budget spendDollars:[iTransaction returnAmount]];
                        break;
                case credit:
                        [budget changeForeignCurrency:[iTransaction returnAmount]];
                        break;
                default:
                        break;
         }
        }

        Budget* europeBudget = [Budget new];
        [europeBudget createBudget:1000.00 withExchangeRate:1.2500];

        Budget* englandBudget = [Budget new];
        [englandBudget createBudget:2000.00 withExchangeRate:1.5000];

        NSMutableArray* transactions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
        Transaction* aTransaction;
        for(int n=1;n<2;n++){
                aTransaction = [CashTransaction new];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 forBudget:europeBudget];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];

                aTransaction = [CashTransaction new];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 forBudget:englandBudget];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];  
        }
        int n=1;
        while (n<4) {
                aTransaction = [CreditCardTransaction new];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 forBudget:europeBudget];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];

                aTransaction = [CreditCardTransaction new];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 forBudget:englandBudget];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];

                n++;    
        }
        for(Transaction* aTransaction in transactions){
                [aTransaction spend];
        }
return 0;
}
```

### BudgetObject.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface Budget : NSObject {
        float exchangeRate;
        double budget;
        double exchangeTransaction;
}
- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;
- (void) spendDollars: (double) dollars;
- (void) changeForeignCurrency: (double) foreignCurrency;
@end
```

### BudgetObject.m

```
#import "BudgetObject.h"
@implementation Budget
- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;
{
        budget = aBudget;
        exchangeRate = anExchangeRate;
}
- (void) spendDollars: (double) dollars
{
        budget = budget - dollars;
        NSLog(@"Converting %0.2f into U.S Foreign Currency leaves $%0.2f",dollars,budget);
}
- (void) changeForeignCurrency: (double) foreignCurrency
{
        exchangeTransaction = foreignCurrency * exchangeRate;
        budget = budget - exchangeTransaction;
        NSLog(@"Charging %0.2f in Foreign Currency leaves $%0.2f",foreignCurrency,budget);
}
@end
```

### Transaction.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "BudgetObject.h"
@class Budget;
@interface Transaction : NSObject {
        Budget* budget;
        double amount;  
}
- (void) createTransaction: (double) theAmount forBudget: (Budget*) aBudget;
- (void) trackSpending: (double) theAmount;
- (void) spend;
@end
```

### Transaction.m

```
#import "Transaction.h"
#import "BudgetObject.h"
@implementation Transaction
- (void) createTransaction: (double) theAmount forBudget: (Budget*) anBudget {
        budget = anBudget;
        amount = theAmount;
}
- (void) spend {

}
-(void) trackSpending: (double) theAmount {
        NSLog(@"You are about to spend another %0.2f",theAmount);
}
@end
```

### CashTransaction.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Transaction.h"
@interface CashTransaction : Transaction {

}
@end
```

### CashTransaction.m

```
#import "CashTransaction.h"
#import "BudgetObject.h"
@implementation CashTransaction
- (void) spend{
        [super trackSpending:amount];
        [budget spendDollars:amount];
}
@end
```

### CreditCardTransaction.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Transaction.h"
@interface CreditCardTransaction : Transaction {

}
@end
```

### CreditCardTransaction.m

```
#import "CreditCardTransaction.h"
#import "BudgetObject.h"
@implementation CreditCardTransaction
- (void) spend {
        [self trackSpending:amount];
        [budget changeForeignCurrency:amount];
}
@end
```

### output:

```
2011-04-15 11:24:46.112 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] You are about to spend another 100.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.114 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] Converting 100.00 into U.S Foreign Currency leaves $900.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.115 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] You are about to spend another 100.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.115 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] Converting 100.00 into U.S Foreign Currency leaves $1900.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.116 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] You are about to spend another 100.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.119 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] Charging 100.00 in Foreign Currency leaves $775.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.120 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] You are about to spend another 100.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.120 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] Charging 100.00 in Foreign Currency leaves $1750.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.121 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] You are about to spend another 200.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.121 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] Charging 200.00 in Foreign Currency leaves $525.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.122 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] You are about to spend another 200.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.122 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] Charging 200.00 in Foreign Currency leaves $1450.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.123 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] You are about to spend another 300.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.123 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] Charging 300.00 in Foreign Currency leaves $150.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.124 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] You are about to spend another 300.00
2011-04-15 11:24:46.125 Bud Obj1[1041:a0f] Charging 300.00 in Foreign Currency leaves $1000.00
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`self` and `super` work quite differently: `self` means the calling object at *runtime*, while `super` means the superclass of the class where the method definition is. In both cases they are specifying where the search for a method should start, in the case of `self` the starting point is determined dynamically, in the `super` case it is known at compile time.

Here is a made up example:

```
@interface Grandparent : NSObject

- (void) One;

@end

@implementation Grandparent

- (void) One { NSLog(@"Grandparent One\n"); }

@end

@interface Parent : Grandparent

- (void) One;
- (void) Two;

@end

@implementation Parent

- (void) One { NSLog(@"Parent One\n"); }

- (void) Two
{
    [self One];                 // will call One based on the calling object
    [super One];                // will call One based on the defining object - Parent in this case so will Grandparent's One
}

@end

@interface Child : Parent

- (void) One;

@end

@implementation Child

- (void) One { NSLog(@"Child One\n"); }

@end


@implementation FamilyAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    Child *c = [Child new];
    [c Two];                            // will call the Two inherited from Parent

    Parent *p = [Parent new];
    [p Two];                            // will call Parent's Two
}

@end
```

So we have three classes; `Grandparent`, `Parent` and `Child`; each with a method `One`. Class `Parent has a method`Two`which calls`One`on`self`and`super`. Running this produces:

```
2011-04-15 22:49:05.006 Family[1993:a0f] Child One
2011-04-15 22:49:05.009 Family[1993:a0f] Grandparent One
2011-04-15 22:49:05.009 Family[1993:a0f] Parent One
2011-04-15 22:49:05.010 Family[1993:a0f] Grandparent One
```

For the `Child` case the call `[c Two]` calls the method `Two` that `Child` inherits from its `Parent` - so we have inheritance.

Now as `Two` executes it first calls `[self One]` and `self` is an instance of `Child`, which has a `One`, so `Child`'s `One` is executed - this is inheritance-based polymorphism; at the time of defining `Parent`'s `Two` the future existence of `Child` is unknown but at execution time the call `[self One]` is able to call `Child`'s method .

The next call in `Two` is `[super One]`. Now this is known to refer to `Grandparent`'s `One` at the time of definition.

In general `super` doesn't refer to a method in the superclass (as it does in this example), but to the method an object whose type is the superclass would invoke, e.g. it could belong to, say, `Greatgrandparent`. However whatever method is called can be determined at compile time, as the ancestry of any class is known.

The calls `[self *method*]` and `[super *method*]` can even invoke the same method, found dynamically in the former case, and known statically in the latter.

Hopefully you now can apply inheritance, `self` and `super` to your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I worked on the program you explained me.Thanks for making me to understand about the self and super with an example.

Comment: "and known statically in the latter." No, a `super` call is also dynamic

Comment: @newacct - Are you distinguishing between "found" and "known"? Or are you hinting at the low-level runtime features which allow all sorts of manipulation and fall into the "here be dragons" category? In the standard case the super class, and hence the full inheritance hierarchy, is *known*. If an implementation chooses to *find* a `super` method using a search that is an implementation detail.

Comment: @CRD: I am talking about, for example, if you call a method with `super` and the method is not found, the normal Objective-C message forwarding mechanism (`forwardingTargetForSelector:` and `forwardInvocation:`) operates. So obviously it is not static.

Comment: @newacct - correct, but you're really entering the "here be dragons" territory. Trying `[super` *method* `]` where *method* is not statically determined to be in the hierarchy will produce a warning, and for good reason - its about as close to an error a warning can get. If you get no warnings then the destination is statically known (modulo any low-level chicanery) in the instance case the destination cannot be statically known. Of course you can ignore the warning knowing, say, that you've dynamically added the method to one of your antecedents - but that is surely firmly in the esoteric?

Answer (score 3):

> self  refers to the object receiving a message in objective-C programming.

Invoking a method on the self searches for the method implementation of the method in the usual manner, starting in the dispatch table of the receiving object’s class.

Example: [self startThread]; self.hostReach = YES; BOOL value = self.hostReach;

1.self is also a variable name that can be used in any number of ways, even assigned a new value.
2.Inside an instance method, self refers to the instance; but inside a class method, self refers to the class object.

> super is a flag that tells the compiler to search for the method implementation in a very different place. It begins in the superclass of the class that defines the method where super appears.

Wherever super receives a message, the compiler substitutes another messaging routine for the objc_msgSend function. The substitute routine looks directly to the superclass of the defining class—that is, to the superclass of the class sending the message to super—rather than to the class of the object receiving the message.Messages to super allow method implementations to be distributed over more than one class.

For some tasks, each class in the inheritance hierarchy can implement a method that does part of the job and passes the message on to super for the rest. The init method, which initializes a newly allocated instance, is designed to work like this. Each init method has responsibility for initializing the instance variables defined in its class. But before doing so, it sends an init message to super to have the classes it inherits from initialize their instance variables. Each version of init follows this procedure, so classes initialize their instance variables in the order of inheritance.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html

Answer (score 1):

Super evokes the overwritten method. Thing is, the method in your super is empty.

If I understand your idea correct, then you want to create CashTransactions and CCTransactions, and talk to them using the Transaction class. That way would each call to the Transaction spend method trigger the correct child method. That is polymorphism. You have only to deal with the mother class during runtime. The child does not need the super, unless you leave there some code all children's have in common.