# Using respondsToSelector on delegate vs Superclass

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to parse the difference between a delegate and a superclass in ObjC.

The [docs say I should](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector) use a the SuperClass

```
if( [MySuperclass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)] ) {
    // invoke the inherited method
    [super aMethod];
}
```

I am migrating the following Apple-provided source code to Xamarin / Monotouch

```
- (IBAction)closeButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    id <TapViewControllerDelegate>  strongDelegate;

    #pragma unused(sender)
    strongDelegate = self.delegate;
    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tapViewControllerDidClose:)]) {
        [strongDelegate tapViewControllerDidClose:self];
    }
}
```

**Question**

- What is the difference between the two approaches?
- If possible, can you tell me how I can implement in C# / Xamarin?

Comment: In your case, keep the `[self.delegate respondsToSelector:...]` The doc talks about the `respondsToSelector:` and general, and a potential issue if you want to know if the parent class responds to that method too.

Answer (score 0):

- `- respondsToSelector:` tests whether the *receiving object* will respond to a particular selector.
- `+ instancesRespondToSelector:` tests whether the *an instance of the receiving class* will respond to a particular selector
- `super` is something rather different. It changes the *starting point* for the search for a method which implements the selector in the call.

Searches normally start at the class of the object referenced by `self`, then proceed to the superclass of the class of the object referenced by `self`, etc. Using `super` starts the search at the superclass of the class in which the method containing the `super` call. This *need not* be the same class as the superclass of the object referenced by `self`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673230/objective-c-difference-between-self-and-super/5675894#5675894) for more details.

The found method is still called on `self`.

Given this the call `[obj respondsToSelector:someSelector]` is the same as calling `[[obj class] instancesRespondToSelector:someSelector]`.

A class value *is* itself an object, and to test if a given class responds to a class selector (`+ methodName`) you can send `respondsToSelector:` to it, e.g. `[[obj class] respondsToSelector:someClassSelector]`.

To your examples, first:

```
 [MySuperclass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)]
```

where `MySuperClass` is a class name. This determines whether an *instance* of the superclass of the class in which the method containing this statement is defined will respond to the selector. This determines whether it is safe to call `[super @selector(aMethod)]`.

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector) you references states this is **not** the same as calling `[super respondsToSelector:@selector(aMethod)]` as that checks whether an object of the same type as `self` (and remember that the class in which a method is defined does not need to be the same class as the object `self`, e.g. if class `A` is a sub-class of class `B` and `B` defines a method `M` then `M` can be called with a `self` value which references either an `A` or a `B` instance). If you're not sure about the meaning of `super` see the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673230/objective-c-difference-between-self-and-super/5675894#5675894) referenced above.

Your second example is:

```
[strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tapViewControllerDidClose:)]
```

Here `strongDelegate` is a variable which references an instance of some class. This call determines whether that instance responds to the given selector and so whether it is safe to invoke `[strongDelegate tapViewControllerDidClose:...]`.

HTH